# Unable to mount a file with docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, digital-ocean

I run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up` and I immediately get the error:

```
ERROR: for frontend  Cannot start service frontend: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/c/Users/James/Projects/mysite/frontend/conf/nginx/mysite.template\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/e7a2a699ae3e9ede0dd60b7cfdebb7f2d3adf71e8175157f3c9e88d3285796d2\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/e7a2a699ae3e9ede0dd60b7cfdebb7f2d3adf71e8175157f3c9e88d3285796d2/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
```

My `mysite.template` file exists. I am using digital ocean with `docker-machine`. In development I didn't have this issue running on the same OS (ubuntu 16). I use docker toolbox on windows for development.

Here's the frontend config from `docker-compose.prod.yml`:

```
frontend:
image: nginx:stable-alpine
restart: always
networks:
  - web
  - default
volumes:
  - ${PWD}/frontend/conf/nginx/mysite.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  - ${PWD}/frontend/public:/var/www/html
labels:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.basic.frontend.rule=Host:mysite.com"
  - "traefik.basic.port=80"
```

I followed the instructions from the [docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/). Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: Incase it helps anyone else landing here - if you're using `sudo docker-compose` the ${PWD} will be different. Try `sudo PWD=${PWD} docker-compose up`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only mount host directories as volumes, and not individual files in Docker.

In your `volumes` definition, instead of this:
`- ${PWD}/frontend/conf/nginx/mysite.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

you should do this:
`- ${PWD}/frontend/conf/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d`

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Does `${PWD}/frontend/public:/var/www/html` put the contents of `public/` into `html/`? A little confusing.

Comment: Thank you - i wasted so many hours trying to solve this. Your directory vs file point is vital in order to get this working correctly.