# Docker-compose - Providing XML based configuration to docker container running spring boot standalone application

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I want to know how to configure a docker setup (docker-compose) in order to supply a configuration file which is consumed by my Spring boot application.

The configuration file is called `services.xml` which resides in the applications's `/lib/conf` directory. The file is deployed with the default configuration, however I want the file in host so that whenever I need to change the configuration, I should edit in host and the container would read the updated file.

The docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  my-app:
    image: my-app
    container_name: my-app
    # restart: always
    ports:
      - 8443:8443
    volumes:
      - ./my-app/conf:/opt/lib/my-app/lib/conf:rw
```

**Expected results after running:** `docker-compose up`

I expect this should create the directory, copy the default services.xml (along with all other files in /opt/lib/my-app/lib/conf) in container into this directory to make it available for me to edit.

**Actual results**
After running docker-compose, it creates an empty directory inside the my-app directory. The my-app fails to read the services.xml file and app doesn't start (as it depends on this file).

Comment: have you tried using a absolute path to the file?

Comment: Not yet. How is it different from mapping directories to host and container?

Comment: @Jocke, I am getting error: `mounting \\\"/home/ubuntu/my-app/conf/services.xml\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/87ecda1732ce960a75263ca499b880d29550a70f969f06ba14ce79d1c5e06485/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/87ecda1732ce960a75263ca499b880d29550a70f969f06ba14ce79d1c5e06485/merged/opt/lib/my-app/lib/conf/services.xml\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type`

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711305/unable-to-mount-a-file-with-docker-compose, it is not possible to mount individual files in docker.

Comment: Seems, you would rather need to use a `configuration-server` than trying to map configurations out of the container. If you really need to do this, this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652299/having-docker-access-external-files would be helpful. I don't see, this is the right way anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect this should create the directory, copy the default services.xml (along with all other files in /opt/lib/my-app/lib/conf) in container into this directory to make it available for me to edit.

From you said above, if your aim is to let the contents in container be pop to host & let you have chance to modify them, then I suggest you to use [named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3). But, the folder in host will be managed by docker itself, so you need to find where they are located.

A minimal example for your reference:

**docker-compose.yaml(In my example it located in the folder `77`):**

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    image: alpine
    command: "tail -f /dev/null"
    volumes:
      - my_data:/etc

volumes:
  my_data:
```

**Start the service:**

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/77$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "77_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "77_my_data" with default driver
Creating 77_frontend_1 ... done
```

**Check the location of named volume in host:**

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/77$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE     COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
6635aba545c9    alpine    "tail -f /dev/null"   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes             77_frontend_1
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/77$ docker inspect 77_frontend_1 | grep Source
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/77_my_data/_data",
```

**Check the content of original `/etc/profile` in container:**

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/77$ docker exec 77_frontend_1 cat /etc/profile
export CHARSET=UTF-8
export LANG=C.UTF-8
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
export PAGER=less
export PS1='\h:\w\$ '
umask 022

for script in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
    if [ -r $script ] ; then
            . $script
    fi
done
```

**Modify the script from host:**

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/77$ sudo -s -H
root@shubuntu1:/home/shubuntu1/77# cd /var/lib/docker/volumes/77_my_data/_data
root@shubuntu1:/var/lib/docker/volumes/77_my_data/_data# echo 'echo "hello"' >> profile
```

**Check again the `/etc/profile` in container after we made changes on host:**

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/77$ docker exec 77_frontend_1 cat /etc/profile
export CHARSET=UTF-8
export LANG=C.UTF-8
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
export PAGER=less
export PS1='\h:\w\$ '
umask 022

for script in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
    if [ -r $script ] ; then
            . $script
    fi
done
echo "hello"
```

We can see `echo "hello"` which we add on host already be seen in container.

Comment: This solution is working. Thanks for the detailed answer.